REST API Standard for message exchange between ERP and WMS
I have been trying to find a common messaging standard similar to EDI but where the implementation is using REST APIs that can used for the exchange of information between an ERP and one or more WMS systems.
In particular for these types of entities that need to be exchanged:
ERP outbound

Products
Barcodes
Purchase Orders
Allocations (Distros)
Vendors (Suppliers)
Product Sets
Advance shipping notices

ERP Inbound:

Purchase Order Acknowledgements
Return to Vendor
Purchase Order Acknowledgements
Tracking Statuses for Purchase Orders
Inventory Adjustments
Transfer Adjustments
Cartons Shipped (IBT) by the DC
Cartons Received/Acknowledged by the DC

I have been looking at 3PLS that has as a subset WMS systems, but the REST APIs that I can find Postman collections for does not contain all the entities above and it looks like each of them are rolling their own version.
Some examples of the Postman Collections:

3pl-api-fusion-customer
3PL Systems
3PL partner API

I am also aware that for example WMS Manhattan has in recent versions implemented a Web Service layer that can be called to exchange data, but in this case that would tie me to only their interface.
Does anyone know if such a messaging standard (protocol) exists in the industry?
